# Passing a parameter to a delegate method

Tags: c#, delegates

I have the following scenario:

```
private void RequestInfo(string a, string b)
{
   var c = a+b;
   library.FetchInfo(c, OnInfoReceived);
}

private void OnInfoReceived(CustomParameterType object)
{
   dictionaryOfInfo.Add(c, object);
}
```

As you can see, my problem is that I cannot access variable "c" in the callback passed as argument to FetchInfo function.

Comment: What is the method signature of `library.FetchInfo`?

Comment: FetchInfo is a method from a dll library...nothing I can do to change it. Let's say it receives a string and a callback method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In C# 3.0 and later, you can use a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) like this:

```
private void RequestInfo(string a, string b)
{
   var c = a+b;
   library.FetchInfo(c, obj => dictionaryOfInfo.Add(c, obj));
}
```

Comment: And what if, I want to use the object received and make another async request, and in that callback method use the add to dictionary. Something like this: initial method -> request -> callback -> request -> callback -> add to dictionary.

Comment: Sure, if your method actually does a lot more than just `dictionaryOfInfo.Add`, you can leave it as a method that accepts `c` and `obj` as parameters and call that method inside the lambda expression. But if you really have to do a lot of asynchronous calls, you may want to look into using the [async / await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) pattern instead.